# How to define return type for a function that adds keys to an object dynamically?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following function

```
export function getDateGroups(reviews: Reviews[]): any {
  return reviews.reduce(
    (acc, review: Reviews) => {
      if (review.isGood) {
        return { ...acc, goodReviews: [...acc.goodReviews, review] };
      }

      return { ...acc, badReviews: [...acc.badReviews, review] };
    },
    { goodReviews: [], badReviews: [] }
  );
}
```

Lets say i have the following function. How do i define a return type for the **getDateGroups** function?

I can create a simple interface in this case but i have how do i do it for the condition when the keys that are added are dynamic?

Also can i define a type for the ***acc*** inside the reduce function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define  an interface like the following and use it for both the response and the acc

```
interface ReviewResponse {
  [key: string]: Reviews[]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
type DataResult = {
    goodReviews: Reviews[],
    badReviews: Reviews[]
}
```

try this, since `acc` is the start value which is these, and you are returning reviews.

#### how should look like,

```
type DataResult = {
    goodReviews: Reviews[],
    badReviews: Reviews[]
}
export function getDateGroups(reviews: Reviews[]): DataResult {
    return reviews.reduce(
        (acc: DataResult, review: Reviews) => {
            if (review.isGood) {
                return { ...acc, goodReviews: [...acc.goodReviews, review] };
            }

            return { ...acc, badReviews: [...acc.badReviews, review] };
        },
        { goodReviews: [], badReviews: [] }
    );
}
```

## Edit

with `dynamic` keys

```
type DataResult = {
    [key: string]: Reviews[]
}
```

Comment: I just gave this as an example. I need to add keys dynamically. In this case the keys were static but what if the keys for DataResult are dynamic. How do i handle that case?